# Remove element from list if it's a value of a key more than once

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

So, the problem was hard to condense into the title but here's a detailed explanation.

I have a large dictionary that has thousands of key-value pairs that could have the example below:

```
dict = {'apple' : ['mint', 'nutmeg', 'cinnamon'], 'mint' : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}
```

Notice how the '**apple**' is a key and it has the list as its value, and the list contains the '**mint**' element.

Somewhere in my large dictionary '**mint**' could also be a key and it could have a list of fruits that has the element '**apple**'. As it's the keys in the second element of the dictionary.

The issue is I want to keep the pair of apple and mint, no matter which one is the key or not, but I want a **refined dictionary where they're not forming duplicates**.

So the desired dictionary is either:

```
dict_2 = {'apple' : ['mint', 'nutmeg', 'cinnamon'], 'mint' : ['orange', 'banana']}
```

where the 'apple' element from the list of 'mint' has been removed,

or

```
dict_2 = {'apple' : ['nutmeg', 'cinnamon'], 'mint' : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}
```

where the 'mint' element from the list of 'apple' has been removed.

**EDIT**: I've found the solution to this problem. You can find it below

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Comment: Iterate through `dict.items()` with `(key, value)` and for each value in the dict[key], check if another `(value, key)` exist in the dictionary. If so, remove the pair from either. Also, for fast operation, I would suggest you to use `set` of values for refining. you can later convert it to list or leave it as set if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict = {'apple' : ['mint', 'nutmeg', 'cinnamon'], 'mint' : ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}
```

Since this looks like homework and you haven't shown any work or asked a specific question, I'm going to give you hints for the algorithm, but writing the code is up to you.

You want to

- Iterate over each `key, value` in the dictionary
- e.g. `key = "apple"; value = ['mint', 'nutmeg', 'cinnamon']`

  - Iterate over each element `v` of `value:
  - If `mydict` contains the key `v`,

    - Check if the list at `mydict[v]` contains `key`.
    - If  it doesn't, add the element `v` to a `new_list`
    - If it does, skip adding `v`
  - Set `mydict[key]` to the newly created `new_list`

Translating this to code is pretty easy, and you can even write this as a cool two-liner. If you run into problems and have a *specific* question, feel free to ask!

After running my code for this algorithm on `mydict`, I get:

```
{'apple': ['nutmeg', 'cinnamon'], 'mint': ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']}
```

Comment: appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Code below solves the problem. If anyone would like to show off by making a fancy one-liner, feel free to do so :)

```
    for key, value in my_dict.items(): # iterate over each key, value
        for v in value:
            if v in my_dict.keys() and key in my_dict[v]:
                my_dict[v].remove(key)
            else:
                continue
```